# Error while generating BIRT report in Apache Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, birt

I am new to eclipse and BIRT.

I am getting this error when I am generating report:

> Table (id = 4):
>   + Can not load the report query: 4. Errors occurred when generating the report document for the report element with ID 4. (Element ID:4)

I have google, but I am not getting proper solutions.

This is one solution I found

> INSTALL DATA DRIVER FOR TOMCAT
>
> Go to your downloads and open up the JTDS data driver and look for the `jtds-1.2.3.jar` file. This is the same file we copied earlier to the Eclipse folder. Copy it to
>
> **`C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\Birt-Viewer\WEBINF\
>   platform\plugins\org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc_2.5.0.v20090605\drivers`**
>
> If the `org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc_2.5.0.v20090605\drivers` folder does not exist, simply create it.

---

> INSTALL YOUR REPORT UNDER TOMCAT
>
> Now go and get the report you created earlier, `AddressReport.rptdesign` from the place you saved it to
>   e.g. `C:\BIRT\ AddressReport.rptdesign` and copy it to the Tomcat web server, into the
>   `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\Birt-Viewer` folder.

However, I don't have folder `platform\plugins\org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc_2.5.0.v20090605\drivers` (as specified in the bolded part above) on my computer.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's old, but if someone else get stuck at this. You need to put it inside de "lib" folder, instead of the "platform/plugins". Older versions use "platform/plugins", newer use "lib".